# Notepad ++ problems pasting qutation marks and apostrophes

Tags: notepad++

When I copy text from any website and paste it into notepad++ the apostrophe's and quotes do not paste correctly.  “here” would appear something like ~here~  and  doesn’t  would appear something like doesn~t.
Im using Windows 10. Not sure if that makes any difference. Also, using Notepad V7.7.1 but this issue has been present on all Notepad++ versions that I have used.

Comment: I suspect an encoding problem. What is encoding setting?